# ASP.NET DetailsView return as blank after Insert

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, detailsview

I have two pages: the first it's a gridview that bind to DataSet, the second one have DetailsView that bind to DataSet that is used for editing and inserting.

Upon insertion on DetailsView Page, I want to redirect to GridView Page.

```
if (Request.QueryString["Id"] == null)
{
    //prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
    if (!IsPostBack)
    {
        DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
    }
```

The detail page allow a correct insert of the new record but after saving it return a blank page; how I can obtain to return to an updated gridview page?

I tried to use the ItemInserted event of the DetailsView but it simply don't fire.

Update:

as suggested I add the following code:

```
protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
    Response.Redirect("ms_Ticket.aspx");
}
```

(with ms_Ticket being the gridview page) but the insert continue to return the blank detailsview.

Update:

here's the codebehind of the detail page:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

namespace Rise_cs.Ticket
{
    public partial class WebForm4 : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        static string prevPage = String.Empty;

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (!(Request.UrlReferrer == null))
                {
                    prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                }
            }

            if (Request.QueryString["Id"] == null)
            {
                //prevPage = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
                if (!IsPostBack)
                {
                    DetailsView1.ChangeMode(DetailsViewMode.Insert);
                }



            }


        }

        protected void DetailsView1_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
        {
            Response.Redirect("ms_Ticket.aspx");
        }




    }
}
```

here's the design:

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <generato automaticamente>
//     Codice generato da uno strumento.
//
//     Le modifiche a questo file possono causare un comportamento non corretto e verranno perse se
//     il codice viene rigenerato. 
// </generato automaticamente>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

namespace Rise_cs.Ticket {


    public partial class WebForm4 {

        /// <summary>
        /// Controllo DetailsView1.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Campo generato automaticamente.
        /// Per la modifica, spostare la dichiarazione di campo dal file di progettazione al file code-behind.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.DetailsView DetailsView1;

        /// <summary>
        /// Controllo SqlDataSource1.
        /// </summary>
        /// <remarks>
        /// Campo generato automaticamente.
        /// Per la modifica, spostare la dichiarazione di campo dal file di progettazione al file code-behind.
        /// </remarks>
        protected global::System.Web.UI.WebControls.SqlDataSource SqlDataSource1;
    }
}
```

Update:

here's the complete form code:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Site.Master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="dt_TicketRiga.aspx.cs" Inherits="Rise_cs.Ticket.WebForm4" %>
<asp:Content ID="Content1" ContentPlaceHolderID="HeadContent" runat="server">
</asp:Content>
<asp:Content ID="Content2" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent" runat="server">
    <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
        DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
        <Fields>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Id" HeaderText="Id" InsertVisible="False" 
                ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="Id" />
            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="TicketId" SortExpression="TicketId">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TicketId") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>


                    <asp:Label ID="Label3" runat="server" 
                        Text='<%# Request.QueryString["TicketId"] %>'></asp:Label>

                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text='<%# Bind("TicketId") %>'></asp:Label>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Data" HeaderText="Data" SortExpression="Data" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Ora" HeaderText="Ora" SortExpression="Ora" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="OperatoreId" HeaderText="OperatoreId" 
                SortExpression="OperatoreId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Referente" HeaderText="Referente" 
                SortExpression="Referente" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="ModalitaContattoId" HeaderText="ModalitaContattoId" 
                SortExpression="ModalitaContattoId" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="Descrizione" HeaderText="Descrizione" 
                SortExpression="Descrizione" />
            <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                <EditItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                        CommandName="Update" Text="Aggiorna"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Annulla"></asp:LinkButton>
                </EditItemTemplate>
                <InsertItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="True" 
                        CommandName="Insert" onclick="LinkButton1_Click" Text="Inserisci"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Cancel" Text="Annulla"></asp:LinkButton>
                </InsertItemTemplate>
                <ItemTemplate>
                    <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Edit" Text="Modifica"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="New" Text="Nuovo"></asp:LinkButton>
                    &nbsp;<asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" runat="server" CausesValidation="False" 
                        CommandName="Delete" Text="Elimina"></asp:LinkButton>
                </ItemTemplate>
            </asp:TemplateField>
        </Fields>
    </asp:DetailsView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:GONGConnectionString1 %>" 
        DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM [TicketRighe] WHERE [Id] = @Id" 
        InsertCommand="INSERT INTO [TicketRighe] ([TicketId], [Data], [Ora], [OperatoreId], [Referente], [ModalitaContattoId], [Descrizione]) VALUES (@TicketId, @Data, @Ora, @OperatoreId, @Referente, @ModalitaContattoId, @Descrizione)" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM [TicketRighe] WHERE (([Id] = @Id) AND ([TicketId] = @TicketId))" 
        UpdateCommand="UPDATE [TicketRighe] SET [TicketId] = @TicketId, [Data] = @Data, [Ora] = @Ora, [OperatoreId] = @OperatoreId, [Referente] = @Referente, [ModalitaContattoId] = @ModalitaContattoId, [Descrizione] = @Descrizione WHERE [Id] = @Id">
        <DeleteParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </DeleteParameters>
        <InsertParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TicketId" QueryStringField="TicketId" 
                Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Data" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Ora" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OperatoreId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Referente" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ModalitaContattoId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Descrizione" Type="String" />
        </InsertParameters>
        <SelectParameters>
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Id" QueryStringField="Id" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="TicketId" QueryStringField="TicketId" 
                Type="Int32" />
        </SelectParameters>
        <UpdateParameters>
            <asp:Parameter Name="TicketId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Data" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Ora" Type="DateTime" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="OperatoreId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Referente" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="ModalitaContattoId" Type="Int32" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Descrizione" Type="String" />
            <asp:Parameter Name="Id" Type="Int32" />
        </UpdateParameters>
    </asp:SqlDataSource>
</asp:Content>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try this and let me know ?

```
 protected void dtv_ItemInserted(object sender, DetailsViewInsertedEventArgs e)
{
     Response.Redirect("page.aspx");
}
```

**Edit:** Replace this

```
 <asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" 
    DataKeyNames="Id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px">
```

with

```
<asp:DetailsView ID="DetailsView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateRows="False" DataKeyNames="Id"
            DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" Height="50px" Width="125px" OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted">
        </asp:DetailsView>
```

as you forgot to attach the event to your DetailsView `OnItemInserted="DetailsView1_ItemInserted"`

Comment: Thank you, but even so it just return the blank detail page

Comment: your Detailsview in Updatepanel? please post your complte code behind and DetailsView Code.

Comment: and the DetailsView it's not in an Updatepanel

Comment: ItemInserted is fired ? please post DetailsView Design as well

Comment: The ItemInserted is not fired. I just posted the Design too.

Comment: ...even if the event it's not fired the record it's saved on the table.

Comment: it does not matter , Event should be fired, it will not impact on save, but ItemInserted event fired after insertion of success or not. if you want to redirect, your inserted event should be fired

Comment: I'm checking the firing of the event using a breakpoint in it: it's this method incorrect? What are the possible cause of the event not firing?

Comment: Can you post your all form design; then I can figure out the issue

Comment: I posted the detail form design code: it is enough or it's better if I send also the others page code?

Comment: your inserted event is not attached to your DetailsView and this should be

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem ! After some debug i realized that after the post the DetailViewMode was back to Insert mode ( Default mode that i defined in the aspx file).  To garantee that the values saved were visible after the updated action i had to call the Changemode to garantee that the DetailView stayed on the EditMode.